# Get List of Suppression Email Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is there a way to get bounced emails since last week. Platform that I am targeting is Amazon SES. If we can get the list of email addresses that were bounced since last week through amazon management console. I know it provides us with the number of emails but which emails were bounced and were listed to the suppression list.

Answer (score -2):

Your question been addressed in amazon blog.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/tag/abuse-complaint/

Make sure you are following the procedure to handle [bounces and complaints](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/handling-bounces-and-complaints/) from amazon aws.

Additional links for reference

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-examples.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html

Comment: Could be improved by actually providing the answer in the answer rather than just providing links.  Its not immediately clear how the contents of these links (which may ave changed) addresses OPs question.

Comment: The links are not at all helpful. You can write the answer and share the reference URL to the amazon blog.